# Creating an observable which relies on state from an Interval

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to write a class which will query a set of data out of a database every x seconds.

The issue is that this observable remembers it's previous state and that state is used to determine what is actually sent on the observable.

For Example I want an

```
IObservable<SomeEntity> AddedEntities { get; private set; }
IObservable<SomeEntity> ChangedEntities { get; private set; }
IObservable<SomeEntity> DeletedEntities { get; private set; }
```

My issue is that I have been reading http://www.introtorx.com/ and they say that using Subject is a bad idea. Instead I should be using the Observable.Create methods.

My issue is I only want to query the database once and then send the relevant information back to the correct observable but I dont want each subscribe to my observable start it's own timer and query the database every 5 seconds per subscription to each IObservable.

I have played around with making just one observable which returns a new model with the changed as a set:

```
IObservable<EntityChangeSet> Changes {get; private set;}

public class EntityChangeSet
{
    Public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> Added {get; set;}
    Public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> Changed {get; set;}
    Public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> Deleted {get; set;}
}
```

And I am open to any solution like this as well.

What I have so far is:

```
public class IntervalChangeReader
{
    // My state between ticks.
    private IEnumerable<SomeEntity> knowEntities;

    // Reads the data from the db and uses knowEntities to determine adds, changes, 
    // and deletes which are exposed through properties.
    private DbReaderAndChangeChecker checker;

    IDisposeable timerCancel;

    public IntervalChangeReader(DbReaderAndChangeChecker checker)
    {
        this.checker = checker;
    }

    public IObservable<EntityChangeSet> Changes { get; private set; }

    public Start(int seconds)
    {
        this.timerCancel = Observable.Interval(new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)).Subscribe(
            x => 
            {
                var results = this.checker.Refresh(this.knownEntities);

                // Update this.knownEntities with results.


                // Inform produce a value on the observable ????
                // I could call .OnNext If I had a subject exposed for my Observable.
            }
    }

    public Stop()
    {
        this.timerCancel.Dispose();

        // Complete on all subscriptions?
        // If I were using subjects I could just call .OnComplete here.
    }
}
```

How do I create the Observable without using subjects and how to I pass results through it? I want to do this all with only one timer and not a timer per subscription to my observables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution to my issue.

```
public class IntervalChangeReader
{
    // My state between ticks.
    private IEnumerable<SomeEntity> knowEntities;

    // Reads the data from the db and uses knowEntities to determine adds, changes, 
    // and deletes which are exposed through properties.
    private DbReaderAndChangeChecker checker;

    private EntityChangeSet lastChangeResult;

    public IntervalChangeReader(DbReaderAndChangeChecker checker)
    {
        this.checker = checker;

        // I like to use Do instead of just combining this all into Select to make the side effect obvious.
        this.Changes = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds), scheduler).Do(
            x =>
                {
                    var changes = DbReaderAndChangeChecker.Refresh(this.knownXRefs);

                    // Make changes to knownXRefs which is my state.
                    this.knownXRefs.AddRange(changes.Added);
                    this.knownXRefs.RemoveAll(y => changes.Removed.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id));
                    this.knownXRefs.RemoveAll(y => changes.Changed.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id));
                    this.knownXRefs.AddRange(changes.Changed);

                    lastChangeResult = changes;
                }).Select(x => this.lastChangeResult);

            }

    public IObservable<EntityChangeSet> Changes { get; private set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're after is the `ConnectableObservable` methods...play around with this (note, on phone, so my syntax is likely off a bit)

```
public void Start(int seconds)
{
    // Every tick, generate a "changeset"
    var changeCentral =
        from tick in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds))
        let results = this.checker.Refresh(this.knowEntities)
        select new EntityChangeSet(results);

    // Publish means one subscription for all "connecting" subscribers
    // RefCount means so long as one subscriber is subscribed, the subscription remains alive
    var connector = changeCentral.Publish().RefCount();
    Changes = connector;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. After seeing this and doing more research I think I found a solution.